# junit error - AssertionFailedError

Tags: java, junit

I am new to junit testing and I have the following test -

```
public class ItemsTest extends TestCase {

    private Items itemsd;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        itemsd = new Items();

    }


    @Test
    public void testGetCategory() {
        boolean result = itemsd.getCategory() != null;
        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    }

}
```

Which tests this really really simple code -

```
/**
 * @return Returns the category.
 */
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
```

Obviously I am missing something simple here?

Comment: The test would be easier to read if you write Assert.assertNotNull(itemsd.getCategory());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your `itemsd.getCategory()` returns `null` and so

```
 boolean result = itemsd.getCategory() != null;
```

`result` is `false`, and so the following statement fails to assert

```
 Assert.assertTrue(result);
```